# Django migrations not creating tables on PostgreSQL despite successful execution

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-migration, django-migrations

**Description:**

I'm encountering an issue with Django migrations on a PostgreSQL database. Despite running python manage.py migrate successfully without any errors, the tables are not being created in the database.

**Details:**

**Environment:**

Django version: Django 4.2
PostgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 15.6
Operating System: Ubuntu server 22.04.4

**Issue Description:**

When I run python manage.py migrate, it executes successfully without any errors.
However, upon checking the database, no tables are created in the specified schema.

**Steps I've Taken:**

Checked the permissions for the database user used by Django. It has all privileges, including the ability to create tables.
Verified the configuration in settings.py to ensure the database settings are correct.
Looked for error messages in both the Django logs and PostgreSQL logs, but found no relevant errors.
Specifically created a new PostgreSQL database and user, intentionally not granting any permissions.

**Troubleshooting Attempted:**

Checked the database user permissions.
Examined Django and PostgreSQL logs for errors.
Ensured that migrations are applied in the correct order and do not contain errors.

**Expected Outcome:**

After running python manage.py migrate, I expect the tables specified in the migrations to be created in the PostgreSQL database.

**Additional Context:**

This issue occurs specifically on the production server. On my local machine, the migrations work as expected.
No errors are reported during the migration process, which makes troubleshooting difficult.
Despite intentionally not granting any permissions to the database user, migrations are still reported as successful without any errors.

**Request for Assistance:**

I'm seeking guidance on how to debug this issue further and determine why the tables are not being created despite successful migration execution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Might be helpful if you share the output of your `manage.py migrate` command

Comment: The output of `python manage.py showmigrations` will also help debug your issue.

Comment: We understand you have provided lot of information. But it's better to post actual code being used. Like settings.py, console output ect. Maybe try restarting the server after migration command is executed.